# java-cfenv cloud foundry jdbc connection failure

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, cloud-foundry

deploying spring application to cloud foundry. Cloud foundry has postgres service, trying for jdbc connection using java-cfenv library
application.properties:

```
database.url = #{cfJdbcEnv.findJdbcService().getJdbcUrl()}
database.username = #{ cfJdbcEnv.findJdbcService().getUsername() }
database.password = #{ cfJdbcEnv.findJdbcService().getPassword() }
database.driverClassName = #{cfJdbcEnv.findJdbcService().getDriverClassName()}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="localOverride" value="false" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
  </bean>
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.pivotal.cfenv</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-cfenv-boot</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
          <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
          <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
          <version>42.2.9</version>
        </dependency>
```

Getting error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for postgres://postgres:7cpdezVdlt@apa-svc-xxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.apa.comcast.net:5432/postgres
   2021-03-03T17:35:15.01-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153) ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
   2021-03-03T17:35:15.01-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144) ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
   2021-03-03T17:35:15.01-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:120) ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
   2021-03-03T17:35:15.01-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
   2021-03-03T17:35:15.01-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
   2021-03-03T17:35:15.01-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
   2021-03-03T17:35:15.01-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
   2021-03-03T17:35:15.01-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1435) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
   2021-03-03T17:35:16.00-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [CONTAINER] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   ERROR   No suitable driver found for postgres://postgres:7cpdezVdlt@apa-svc-cd1365a3-c6d0-436b-811d-23fc0ec66f0c.apps.apa.comcast.net:5432/postgres
   2021-03-03T17:35:16.00-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [CONTAINER] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   WARN    SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
```

DataSource object getting instantiated with below code:

```
@Bean(name="dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() { 
        
          DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
          dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName); 
          String url =
          cfEnv.findCredentialsByName("portal-db").getHost(); 
          String username = cfEnv.findCredentialsByName("portal-db").getUsername(); String
          password = cfEnv.findCredentialsByName("portal-db").getPassword();
         
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://"+url+":5432/postgres");
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
}
```

I am not sure why when reading database.url from application.properties file, I am getting error related to wrong url: postgres://postgres:xxxx:5432/postgres

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it seems to be getting the information. It just does not recognize the JDBC URL that's being provided by your service broker.

I would suggest the following:

1. Run `cf env` (or look at the env variables in some other way[1]) and look at `VCAP_SERVICES`. Look for the property that you are trying to target and confirm that the service broker has a JDBC URL set that starts with `jdbc:` all JDBC URLs should start with `jdbc:`.

   As a side note, I think the format that's present use to work with the Spring Cloud Connectors, the predecessor library java-cfenv. I believe it would automatically insert the `jdbc:` part. Your broker may be specifying a JDBC URL that's not strictly a JDBC URL & depending on SCC to correct that.
2. If you are able to confirm that the URL is just missing the leading `jdbc:` then you can a.) contact the maker of your service broker (who makes the integration with CF) and ask them to fix this and b.) adjust the way that you're setting the `database.url` in application.properties to see if you can reformat it in the correct way.

   Perhaps something like this (although I didn't test it):

   ```
   database.url = jdbc:#{cfJdbcEnv.findJdbcService().getJdbcUrl()}
   ```
3. I believe there's a known issue for this, see https://github.com/pivotal-cf/java-cfenv/issues/127 and there is a code commit linked. So it looks like this should eventually start working, once a new release is cut & you upgrade to that release. You can monitor the Github issue for more details. **UPDATE** this should be fixed in release 2.3.0+.

[1] - Other ways you could look at the env variables: `cf ssh` into the container & `cat /proc/<pid>/environ` or dump the env variables through the spring boot actuator `/env` endpoint.

Comment: Did you disable autoreconfiguration and manually enable the cloud profile in the buildpack? https://github.com/pivotal-cf/java-cfenv#pushing-your-application-to-cloud-foundry If you left autoreconfiguration enabled, it could compete and overwrite your data source. You could also try putting `foo-bar` or some nonsense into the `database.url` property and see if the error changes to indicate your nonsense URL or if it still has the `postgres://` url.

Comment: No matter what I configure in database.url, I am getting error ```ERROR   No suitable driver found for postgres://postgres:7cpdezVdlt@apa-svc-cd1xxxxx-23fc0ec66f0c.xxxxxxnet:5432/postgres```. I have also disabled auto-reconfiguration in manifest.yml file environment properties:
```---
applications:
- name: portal
  buildpacks: 
  - https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git#v4.19.1
  services:
  - portal-db
  env:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: cloud
      JBP_CONFIG_SPRING_AUTO_RECONFIGURATION: '{enabled: false}'
```

Comment: I am not using spring boot in my application. Which javacfenv dependency should I add? instead of ```<dependency>
  <groupId>io.pivotal.cfenv</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-cfenv-boot</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>``` dependency

Comment: Try https://github.com/pivotal-cf/java-cfenv/releases/tag/v2.3.0, that should have the fix for issue #127. It should work with postgres URLs in the format you have.

Comment: Please check my original post. I have added some working code.

Comment: Sorry, I really can't help further unless you can link me to a complete, runnable application that reproduces the problem. Perhaps someone else can jump in and help, but that's as much as I can say without seeing the whole picture.